# BIRT - dynamically add columns

Tags: java, dynamic, birt, crosstab

I am trying to generate a BIRT report based on the following (simplified) SQL tables:

- `Product (ProductCode, ProductDescription, RRP)` - this table has products which are sold and the attributes of the product.
- `StockOnHand (ProductCode, WarehouseName, QtyOnHand)` - this table indicates how much of each product is on hand, in each warehouse.

Now I'd like to generate a report where each row shows each product and its attributes, as well as the stock on hand in various warehouses. But I don't know ahead of time which warehouses to show the stock on hand for, as this will be passed as a report parameter.

So the columns of the report would look something like the following:
`ProductCode,ProductDescription,RRP,Warehouse1StockOnHand,Warehouse2StockOnHand,...,WarehouseNStockOnHand`

I'm not clear on the best way to generate a dynamic set of columns. I've come across one solution which is based on [building the report in Java code](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Java_-_Build_Dynamic_Table_(BIRT)).

I am wondering if there is a simpler solution which does not involve writing custom Java code?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is a BIRT cross tab report.
Alternatively - if you don't like BIRT cross tabs - you can create your "cross tab" using SQL pivot or SQL analytic functions and then use a simple table item in BIRT:

Comment: The crosstab seems to be well suited for having the dynamic column set, i.e. the set of columns for the stock on hand. But I was struggling a bit to understand how to get all the product attributes into the crosstab. With the product code as the dimension, how would I get the other attributes like product description, rrp, etc. to show as columns in the crosstab?

Comment: Can't help you. I avoid using cross tabs if possible.